# Handle scrollview items in UICollectionViewCell (the cell is not appearing )

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uiscrollview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm making a horizontal UICollectionView, and inside UICollectionViewCell I have scrollView that contains a stackView of UITextField.

My issue is the cell is not appearing and none of the items is displayed and I just have white content. Even when I tried to connect the UItextField with the OUtlet I face this error.

```
Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value
```

PS: I have linked all the classes with the UIViews, and the referencing outlets are perfectly done for me. and I did add this registration cell line and I've added all the needed functions to the UICollectionView.

```
self.descriptionCollectionView!.register(DescriptionCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "DescriptionCell")
```

I have looked through the questions asked on stack overflow but none of them is similar to mine

here is what  am trying to do inside the UICollectionViewCell :
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you open break point navigator (`⌘` + `8`) and add an exception break point for your debugging? Please also share your stack-trace in your original question.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I Was trying to use a custom cell from the storyboard without using the NIb file, and then I decided the change using it and it worked! 
I still don't know, if I have to use a Nib every time I need a custom cell? because according to my research a NIB file is going to be created automatically if I don't create it myself. 
Any idea, please?

Comment: I guess you are referring to a `prototype cell` by `custom cell from the storyboard ` and `Nib` to a `.xib` file. both should work. `if I have to use a Nib every time I need a custom cell` No, both approach should work fine here.

`NIB file is going to be created automatically` -- did not get your point. Are you taking about availability of having an option to create .xib while creating table or collection view cell subclass? in each case you need to add additional UI element to fulfill your requirement. Try https://www.toptal.com/ios/ios-user-interfaces-storyboards-vs-nibs-vs-custom-code

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But the thing that made me confused is; when I switch to use the .xib file I didn't change anything other than adding the register cell. And everything worked well by then.